# CreateObject vb6

Tags: .net, com, vb6

I am working on an existing app that is in VB6 which is calling a .NET DLL.
but my .NET code is not reflecting when it is called from the VB6 app.
I have added one public propertt in the .NET app but when I try to access it, VB6 raises an exception:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

My PostBuild event Code.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe $(ProjectDir)bin\$(TargetName).dll  /regfile:$(TargetName).reg
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe $(ProjectDir)bin\$(TargetName).dll  /tlb:$(TargetName).tlb
```

I can see registry CLSID is changing.
But code is not reflecting when calling from VB6
(Object doesn't support this property or method)

VB6 Code

```
Set frmApp = CreateObject("AssemblyName.Class1")
```

Do I need to do any other setting?

How to set references in VB6 to the new classid?

Comment: What do you mean by "But code is not reflecting when calling from VB6?". Post the code you are using to instantiate the object.

Comment: Have you tried adding /codebase to your RegAsm commands?

Answer (score 3):

You can mark your .Net classes with the [ProgId attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute.progidattribute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). This will prevent your clsid from changing everytime you compile.

If the clsid does not change, you do not have to un- and re-register your classes.

After a re-register, you also need to set your references in VB6 to the new classid. VB6 uses the clsid to search for the component.

**After comment**
VB6 has been a long time ago. I don't know if "reference" is the correct term. But you should remove the depency on the old library. And add a dependency to the new, just like you did the first time.

Comment: How to set references in VB6 to the new classid ?

Comment: @GvS @gauravghodnadikar "Reference" is the correct term. In the VB6 IDE use the menu command Project-References to access the dialog

Comment: @MarkJ, thanks. Just like VBA (Word macro) as I thought it was.

Comment: I have addded reference to .tlb file but I am still cannot view my changes in >net form. Can i debug from which location this DLL getting load.

Comment: Via the Registry, you can find the ClsID that is connected to a class name. And with this ClsID you can find the library that it points to.

Comment: I am still getting same error. 1)I have build my .Net code with RegAsm.exe /regfile 2)RegAsm.exe /tlb (No codebase switch used) 3)Copy new DLL same folder as VBP 4)Form is not changed as per new changes and when try to access newly created prop then getting error Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1):

"Not reflecting" is *very* unclear.  But as posted, these regasm.exe commands are *not* sufficient to let a VB6 program find the assembly.  If it doesn't complain about creating the class object then you've used gacutil.exe some time in the past.  And the GAC contains an old copy of your DLL.  You will have to remove that old copy, use gacutil.exe /u

Modify the regasm.exe command line, add the /codebase option so it always uses the copy of DLL in the build directory instead of looking for the DLL in the GAC.

Comment: I am still getting same error. 1)I have build my .Net code with RegAsm.exe /regfile 2)RegAsm.exe /tlb (No codebase switch used) 3)Copy new DLL same folder as VBP 4)Form is not changed as per new changes and when try to access newly created prop then getting error Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @gauravghodnadikar Have you read Hans' answer carefully? VB6 doesn't call local copies of DLLs from the VBP directory or anywhere else, it requires them to be registered in the GAC (see note later). Therefore you must have an old copy in the GAC. You need to unregister it `gacutil.exe /u` and then register the new one with '/codebase'. (Note) you can use manifests to persuade VB6 to load DLLs from the local directory but that's a bit advanced, I suggest you get this working first and come back to that later.

Comment: Done... I samply copy my DLL to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98 and its working no need to deploy in GAC or /Codebase switch

Answer (score 0):

Done... I simply copied my DLL to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98 and its working no need to deploy in GAC or /Codebase switch

Comment: Kinda sucks to have to install Visual Studio on every machine that runs your code.